# Sync work items between Azure devops server to Azure devops Cloud

Tags: azure-devops

We have a use case where epics and features are maintained in Azure DevOps cloud and user stories in Azure DevOps Server.

Now we are looking for some kind of connectors to sync the data to get complete traceability in Azure DevOps Cloud?

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I'm having the same problem, In my company we have Azure DevOps on premises and on cloud and we want to sync the action items between them. We are looking for an automatic solution to do so

Answer (score 0):

You can export work items from server and then import them to service using CSV. Here are the detailed steps:

1. In Azure DevOps Server, go to "Boards/Queries". Create a query to include all work itmes you want to export. Click "Column options" to include all fields you want. Then click "Export to CSV" to download a CSV file.[image]
2. Open the CSV file. Delete the ID column and save the change.

   [image]
3. In Azure DevOps Service, go to "Boards/Work items". Click "Import Work Items". Choose the CSV file in step 2. Finally, save the work items.

Some other advices:

1. REST APIs: You can get work items by [Work Items - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/list?view=azure-devops-server-rest-5.0). Then use them as request bodies to create work items by [Work Items - Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0).
2. Use [Azure DevOps Server migration tool](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/devops/migrate/). However, this tool is more complex to use and requires specific server versions. Click the previous link to download the guide.

Comment: @user6936970 As of this time, however, syncing work items between Azure DevOps and Azure DevOps Server is not supported.